# Click and change THIS div

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have 3 divs with the same class (i can't use IDs on them). I find all of them by targeting their class and then - on click - i want to apply some stuff (e.g. change background-color). i only managed to change all of them, but not only the one i'm actually clicking. what am i missing?

```js
var thisDiv = $('.thisDiv');

thisDiv.click(function() {
  var i = thisDiv.index(this);

  console.log(i);
  console.log(thisDiv.css('background-color'));

  // this changes all of the div, not only the clicked one
  thisDiv.css('background-color', 'red');

  // console msg for the code below: Uncaught TypeError: thisDiv[i].css is not a function
  // thisDiv[i].css('background-color', 'red');

  // i also tried these, which didn't work...
  //console.log(thisDiv[i].css('background-color'));
  //console.log(thisDiv.eq[i].css('background-color'));
});
```

```css
.thisDiv{width:50px;height:50px;background-color:lightgrey;float:left;margin:15px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thisDiv">div 0</div>
<div class="thisDiv">div 1</div>
<div class="thisDiv">div 2</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.eq()`:

```
thisDiv.eq(i)
```

as `thisDiv` is a collection of objects, you can get the specific ones with `$(this)` or `.eq(i)`.

```js
var thisDiv = $('.thisDiv');

thisDiv.click(function() {
  var i = thisDiv.index(this);
  thisDiv.eq(i).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

```css
.thisDiv {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thisDiv">div 0</div>
<div class="thisDiv">div 1</div>
<div class="thisDiv">div 2</div>
```

Comment: Thx a lot, $(this) - as in yours and the other answer works - but the .eq() was what i was looking for! thx a lot..

Answer (score 2):

use `$(this)` will give you the div which you have clicked

```
  $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
```